# file not being uploaded to php

Tags: javascript, php, html

Im trying to upload a file to wamp server and is_upload_file returns false for for files over 10mb. Everything work fine for smaller files.

**HTML**

```
<button  type = "button" id = "uploadbutton">Click</button>
<form id = "fileupload">
    <input type="file" name = "uploadfile" id = "uploadfile" style="position: fixed; top: -100em; display:none">
</form>
```

**js**

```
var uploadbutton = document.getElementById("uploadbutton");
var uploadFileInput = document.getElementById("uploadfile");

uploadbutton.onclick = function()
{
    uploadFileInput.click();
};

uploadFileInput.onchange = function()
{
    onSubmitFile();
};

function onSubmitFile()
{
    console.log("onsubmitform");
    var fd = new FormData(document.getElementById("fileupload"))

    $.ajax({
        url: "uploadfile.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: fd,
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        processData: false,  
        contentType: false
    }).done(function( data ) {
        alert(data);
    });
}
```

**PHP**

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadfile"]["tmp_name"]))
{
    $name = $_FILES["uploadfile"]["name"];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadfile"]["tmp_name"], "C:\\$name");
    echo $_FILES["uploadfile"]["name"];
    echo "File uploaded";
}
else
{
    echo "File not uploaded";
}
print_r($_FILES);
```

`print_r($_FILES)` prints an empty array when `is_uploaded_file` fails.

in **php.ini**

upload_max_filesize 64M
post_max_size 20M
max_input_time 300
max_execution_time 300

Comment: Refer this: http://www.sitepoint.com/upload-large-files-in-php/ Also note `display : none` may trouble you in mobile devices. If you want to hide it then set width and height to `0px`

Comment: what is the purpose of is_uploaded_file() method. can you share the code of this method?

Comment: @AmitRajput, [`is_uploaded_file — Tells whether the file was uploaded via HTTP POST`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php)

Comment: Try this link ajax file upload not support all browser ...https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

Comment: @rayon i updated my post with my php.ini and they seem fine for what im uploading. rahal it works fine with smaller files.

Comment: @rahul, It would be helpful if the concern would be `IT DOES NOT WORK`, but in this case, it does not work only if file is large.

Comment: Are you using Wampserver ?

Comment: _(left click ) wampmanager icon -> PHP -> php.ini_ this is the way you are accessing it ? Also check `phpinfo()`

Comment: @RayonDabre yea and phpinfo() returns alot php license and info

Comment: Does this info matches the values set in `ini` ?

Comment: @RayonDabre it does not post_max_size is at 3M but when i open it in nopepad++ where i edited it its at 20M

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98637/discussion-between-rayon-dabre-and-devguy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it turns out i was editing the wrong php.ini.
i edited the ini in Apache folder and everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Please update below variables settings in php.ini file then try.

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('post_max_size', '50M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '50M');
```

Thanks

Comment: 50 MB data will at least take 15 minutes to upload. What about maximum execution time ?

Comment: You can update the size limit according to your requirements.

Comment: I am talking about `max_execution_time` but note that what is file is 1GB large ? How long will it take to upload ? _Chunked file uploads_ is the way to go in that case..

Comment: @VinodPatidar i updated my post with my php.ini values and they seem file for what im uploading

Comment: Yes, my dear if your file is larger than 1 GB etc you should go with  Chunked file uploads.

Comment: You can use this script: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Chunked-file-uploads

Comment: @VinodPatidar the file is only 10 mb

Comment: Check my answer I've updated maximum execution time if your script has timeout issue.

Answer (score 2):

Please update below variables settings in php.ini file then try or make the changes in the ini file and restart your server

```
ini_set('post_max_size', '50M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '50M');
```

Answer (score 1):

Update below variables settings then try..

```
ini_set('post_max_size', '50M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '50M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 1200); // 1200 seconds i.e. 20 minutes
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Form Should look like this:

```
   <form action="formprocess.php" id='fileupload' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```